# How to update an existing array of objects (add a new object to the array) with the useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

I have an onChange handler with which I can edit certain objects with input fields.

The onChange handler looks like this:

```
// First I get the current state
const [persons, setPersons] = useState(service.persons);
```

The API returns the following for persons (an array of objects):

```
contacts (2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {person_company: "Google", person_name: "John Doe"}
1: {person_company: "Facebook", person_name: "Jane Doe"}
```

My onChange handler looks like this *(..first part of the if statement for editing the given persons works perfectly, but the else statement for creating a new person doesn't):*

```
const updatePersons = (e: any, index?: number) => {
  if (index !== undefined) {
    const updatedPersons = [...persons];
    updatedPersons[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setPersons(updatedPersons);
  } else {
    setPersons({ ...persons, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
};
```

My template looks like this *(just empty input fields for creating a new person with a person_company and person_name):*

```
<InputContainer>
  <p>New person</p>
  <InputWrapper>
    <TextField
      type="text"
      label="Person company"
      name='person_company'
      value=' '
      onChange={e => updatePersons(e)}
    />
  </InputWrapper>
  <InputWrapper>
    <TextField
      type="text"
      label="Person name"
      name="person_name"
      value=' '
      onChange={e => updatePersons(e)}
    />
  </InputWrapper>
</InputContainer>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way.

1. Only the first letter is realized in the first input field and the whole component disappears afterwards
2. If I manipulate it so that the component does not disappear, the value of the input field is not updated (this is probably because I set value = ' '. I have no idea what else I should provide).
3. If I console log persons after the first letter as mentioned in 1., the array of object is updated as follows:

   ```
   contacts {0: {…}, 1: {…}, company_name: " t"}
   0: {person_company: "Google", person_name: "John Doe"}
   1: {person_company: "Facebook", person_name: "Jane Doe"}
   person_company: " t"
   ```

But my goal is that the object should be updated as follows when I create a new person:

```
contacts (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {person_company: "Google", person_name: "John Doe"}
1: {person_company: "Facebook", person_name: "Jane Doe"}
2: {person_company: "Amazon", person_name: "Max Mustermann"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

try this dont spread a list inside of object, and instead spread a list and add object, also because when you call a new person there is no index provided  :

```
const updatePersons = (e: any, index?: number) => {
  if (index !== undefined) {
    const updatedPersons = [...persons];
    updatedPersons[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setPersons(updatedPersons.map((person)=>({...person,new:false})));
  } else {
      const lastPerson = persons.slice(-1)[0];
      if (lastPerson.new){
          setPersons([...persons.slice(0,-1), {...lastPerson ,[e.target.name]:e.target.value}]);
      } else {
          setPersons([...persons,{[e.target.name]:e.target.value , new:true}]
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: With this approach it adds a new object for every keystroke and I get the following after typing "test" in the person_company input field (and the value in the input field still doesn't update): https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-fast-tfu60?file=/src/example.json

Comment: you also need to provide the index when you call `onChange={e => updatePersons(e)}` so `onChange={e => updatePersons(e,index)}`, or you need to think of other way to keep the 'new person' index even after incrementing the list size

Comment: please infrom me if went well... good luck

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach didn't work. But I solved it differently - I adapted the updatePersons method, which now only processes the cases with an ID (so no else block anymore). Instead, I now do everything directly in the onChange handler of the textfields to create a new person. I have also created a submitHandler in which I update the state and empty the form fields afterwards. I'll post the approach as an answer. Let me know if the solution is acceptable as well.

Comment: Good luck! I dont see a reason to post the answer but go for it if you wish..

Comment: Many Thanks. I posted my approach as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't solve it using the approaches suggested. But I did it in a different way.

I adapted the updatePersons method, which now only processes the cases with an ID (so no else block anymore).

```
const updatePersons = (e: any, index?: number) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // is this needed here?
  if (index !== undefined) {
    const updatedPersons = [...persons];
    updatedPersons[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setPersons(updatedPersons);
  }
};
```

Instead, I now do everything directly in the onChange handler of the textfields to create a new person.

```
// I created another useState hook for the new Person 
// ..and provided an initial state (empty strings) by instantiating a new Person:

const [newPerson, setNewPerson] = useState(new Person());
```

My textfields now look like this:

```
  <InputWrapper>
    <TextField
      type="text"
      label="Person name"
      name="person_name"
      value=' '
      onChange={e => setNewPerson({ ...newPerson, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
    />
  </InputWrapper>
```

I have also created a submit handler in which I update the state and empty the form fields afterwards.

```
  const submitHandler = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // is this needed here?
    setPersons([...persons, newPerson]);
    setNewPerson(new Person()); // Empty the form fields
  };
```

Let me know if this solution is also ok.

Comment: Yes it does :).